# What does this [Option(...)] C# attribute mean?

Tags: c#

What does this C# attribute mean? I am mostly working with C++,
and I do know about the concept of attributes in C#, but not sure about this one:
It is in a class. So basically we have a property, and an attribute for it.

```
[Option("h", "help", HelpText = "Shows this help message")]
public bool Help { get; set; }
```

Thanks

Comment: Trace back where (which namespace) `Option` comes from.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a Command Line Option from one of the Console application libraries that help to parse command line arguments.

It might be from the [Command Line Parser tool](http://commandline.codeplex.com/) which has very similar syntax to your example.

Comment: Can this answer be updated? the link to the Command Line Parser Tool works no more.

Answer (score 3):

Attributes is a way to associate information with your C# code.

For example if you want to make your method a web method , you apply the **webmethod** attribute

```
[WebMethod]
void myfunction() ...
```

While working with web services and you want to serialize the custom objects, you can apply the serialize attribute

```
[Serializable]
public class MyObject {
  public int n1 = 0;
  public String str = null;
}
```

if your want to use the **user32.dll** for some windows related task , you can import the function using the dllimport attribute as follows

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
extern static void SampleMethod();
```

For more you can see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: He said he _does_ know about attributes. So no need to explain it again.